# Broken Upgrade to Unity 2021.3.16f1, Callback provided streaming assets file conflicts with file already present in project

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle, build, upgrade

When I attempted to upgrade to 2021.3.16f1 and more specifically Targeting API 31-33 I have been unable to successfully build my project, I receive this error:

```
error: Callback provided streaming assets file conflicts with file already present in project. Project file 'StreamingAssets/UnityServicesProjectConfiguration.json'. Callback provided file 'Library/com.unity.services.core/UnityServicesProjectConfiguration.json'.
System.ArgumentException: Callback provided streaming assets file conflicts with file already present in project. Project file 'StreamingAssets/UnityServicesProjectConfiguration.json'. Callback provided file 'Library/com.unity.services.core/UnityServicesProjectConfiguration.json'.
   at PlayerBuildProgramLibrary.PlayerBuildProgramBase.SetupDataFiles()
   at PlayerBuildProgramLibrary.PlayerBuildProgramBase.SetupPlayerBuild()
   at AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.SetupPlayerBuild()
   at PlayerBuildProgramLibrary.PlayerBuildProgramBase.RunBuildProgram()
   at PlayerBuildProgramTypeWrapper.Run(String[] args)
   at Program.Main(String[] args)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

I have attempted to remove the .json at both locations, the one in the Library Files results in a different gradle build error which I have had no luck solving and the one in Steaming assets rebuilds itself on build. I have reverted to an earlier working version and attempted to repeat the steps to upgrade to the latest version. I am at a loss all ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting only the json file at `Assets/StreamingAssets/UnityServicesProjectConfiguration.json` did the trick for us.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Cleaning the addressables' build (from the addressable group build menu) fixed this for me.

EDIT: A better solution for me was to just wipe out everything inside Assets/StreamingAssets and Assets/StreamingAssets/aa
and use the copy in the library folder. But play around and see which copy you should keep, as it may be different for different situations.